# Is there any similar function in gocv like np.where() in python?

Tags: python, opencv, go

Is there any similar function in Gocv like np.where() in Python? I want to specify some specific pixel values to 0, and others to 255. As follows, in Python I can do:

```py
        img = cv2.imread("test.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img_ = np.where(img == 144 , img*0, np.where(img == 170 , img*0, np.where(img == 178 , img*0, np.where(img == 187 , img*0, 255))))
```

the pixel values which are 187, 178, 170, 144 will be set to 0, and others to 255. How can I do this job in Golang with Gocv?

Comment: see this pachage https://www.gonum.org/

Comment: I think I need a method to manipulate the gocv.Mat like np.where.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found out that there is nothing like np.where() in gocv.
All I have to do is:

1. get []byte using Mat.ToBytes()
2. writing a for loop to check each pixel in []byte and changing it if meet the condition.
3. get Mat from gocv.NewMatFromBytes()

Comment: For point 2 - how do you check each pixel in `[]byte`?